# Jquery URL Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery and AJAX to fetch some data from a PHP file which is stored remotely on a server. I was able to fetch the first page and display the results in an HTML table. I am facing another issue now: I am trying to fetch all the pages and then make a pagination for all of these pages.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Food Hygiene Ratings</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap  /3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<style>

header {
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px;} 

footer {
background-color: black;
color: white;
clear: both;
ext-align: center;
padding: 5px; }

th, td {
text-align: center;
padding: 8px; }

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #e65c00}

th {
background-color: #000000;
color: white; }} 

</style>


<script> 

$.getJSON("http://xxx.ac.uk/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/hygiene/hygiene.php?op=retrieve&page=1", function(data){$.each(data, function(index,el){
$("#id").append("<tr><td>"+el.business+"</td><td>"+el.address+"</td><td>"+el.rating+"</td><td>"+el.date+"</td></tr>"); })}); 


</script>



</head>


<header><h1>Food Hygiene Ratings</h1></header>

<p><center>This page will display the results of the fast food shops and restaurants located in and around London</center></p>


<center><table width="1032" height="41" id="id"  style=width:95%">
<tr>
<th width="130">Business</th>
<th width="130">Address</th>
<th width="100">Rating</th>
<th width="100">Date</th>
</tr>
</table></center>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php
 // Load the XML file from the same location as this script
 if(file_exists('city.xml')) {
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("city.xml");
 } else {
 exit('Failed to open city.xml');
 }

 // Copy the values of the relevant elements of the XML into a PHP array.
 // We're not copying everything, and we're changing the names
 // Cast to (string) is so we don't copy the SimpleXMLElement objects
 $i = 0 ; $json = array();
 foreach($xml->EstablishmentCollection->EstablishmentDetail as $elem) {
 $json[$i]['id'] = (string) $elem->FHRSID;
 $json[$i]['business'] = (string) $elem->BusinessName;
 $json[$i]['address'] = $elem->AddressLine1.', '.$elem->AddressLine2.',     '.$elem->PostCode;
$json[$i]['rating'] = (string) $elem->RatingValue;
$json[$i]['date'] = (string) $elem->RatingDate;
$i++;
}

 $numpages = (int) ((sizeof($json) + 39) / 40);

 // Output the JSON encoding of $len elements of the array, starting at $start
 // Stop if we hit the end of the array
 function generate($start, $len) {
 global $json;

 echo('[');
 for($i = $start; $i < ($start + $len); $i++) {
     if(!array_key_exists($i, $json)) break;    // stop at end of array
     if($i != $start) echo(',');
     echo(json_encode($json[$i]));
 }
 echo(']');
 }

 // Search the business names in the array and output the JSON version of any matches
// Limit 40 matches
 function search($str) {
 global $json;

 $i = 0;

 echo('[');
 foreach($json as $elem) {
     if(strpos($elem['business'], $str) !== false) {
         // matches, encode it
         if($i != 0) echo(',');
         echo(json_encode($elem));
         $i++;
         if($i == 40) break;    // enough
     }
 }
 echo(']');
 }

 // Default operation
 if(empty($_GET['op'])) {
generate(0, 10);
return;
}

$op = $_GET['op'];
if($op == 'demo') {
     generate(0,10);
} elseif($op == 'pages') {
 echo('{"pages": '.$numpages.'}');
 } elseif($op == 'retrieve') {
 if(empty($_GET['page'])) die('Retrieve with no page number');
 $pageno = (int) $_GET['page'];
 if(($pageno < 1) || ($pageno > $numpages)) die('Page requested out of range: '.$pageno);
 generate(40 * ($pageno - 1), 40);
 } elseif($op == 'searchname') {
 if(empty($_GET['name'])) die('Empty search string');
 search($_GET['name']);
 } else die('Unknown op: '.$op);
 ?>
```

Comment: can you show us your php code as well ? And did you try to display a pagination for a begining ?

Comment: I added the PHP script it is server side So I am fetching it from an URL. The code I have fetches only the firts page of results. I need a function to fetch all the pages and then create a pagination for them.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: Yes I have. Instead of using this :$.getJSON("http://xxx.ac.uk/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/hygiene/hygiene.php?op=retrieve&page=1.

I replaced it like this:
$.getJSON("http://xxx.ac.uk/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/hygiene/hygiene.php?op=pages.

but it doesn't seem to work fetching all pages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you are using ajax, you could load only the requested pages instead of all the pages once.

You can retrieve the number of pages using hygiene.php?op=pages

then you know how many pages you'll have to display, you can display your pages link and load the first page.

to load a page : hygiene.php?op=retrieve&page=1

or page number 2 for example hygiene.php?op=retrieve&page=2

Comment: So you are saying I cannot request all pages at once using op=pages I have to request all of them one by one and then create pagination for them?

Comment: I found out that there are 40 pages of results. How can I request all those and create pagination for them which means I will have 40 buttons from 1-40.

Comment: what is the interest of loading all of them if the user only wants to see the first page ? This is the interest of ajax : to minify requests and load only the wanted data. Imagine if you have 500 pages and you load all the info.
What I'm saying is that nothing allows you to fetch all the data in once in your php code unless you edit it. So the only solution you have would be to construct the pagination buttons first and then display the requested pages.

Comment: you just have to call hygiene.php?op=pages to get how many pages have to be displayed, then you can display the pagination buttons the way you ant, you d'ont have to display all 40 of them !

Comment: if you really want to get all the data you'll have to edit the php file since it doesn't allow such operation for the moment.

Comment: What will be the full code to do this? Because when I use hygiene.php?op=pages nothing displays.

Comment: It's normal hygiene.php?op=pages just returns the number of pages !! I explained all that to you already, do you even read ?? This is a help website, not a "do it in my place" website, you'll have to try at least.
I repeat : first, you have to call hygiene.php?op=pages to get the number of pages, then when you can display your pagination, and when you click on a page button you call  hygiene.php?op=retrieve?page=X where X is the page clicked !

Comment: Ok. It returns 45 pages of results. What can I use for pagination I tried using Bootstrap but for example when I put the link to the page in the <a href it displays the page but the results are not sorted in a table.

Comment: @jiboulex That isn't how query strings work. You don't use `?` to separate pairs in the string, you use `&`.

Comment: oh it was a mistake sorry